# Is it possible to create a paper.js PointText object with multiple colors and font sizes?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm working on an image annotator that utilizes `paper.js` `PointText` objects for part of it. One thing we're looking into is allowing the user to highlight different parts of the text of a given `PointText` object with different colors and font sizes.

I saw the `Gradient` option on the `paper.js` website, but that would feel like more of a hack to get working, assuming it would work in the first place. Then I would have to get it to display properly in the `textarea` used for editing the `PointText`, which sounds even more hacky; I would like a cleaner solution.

Any solutions must allow the text to be draggable within the bounds of the canvas.

I don't have any code to show because I haven't found anything to try, but I wanted to see if the SO community is aware of any possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think text tools are still in development in Paper.js*, so I guess you have to create one PointText by color or use gradients as you suggested if you want to stick with Paper.js.

In my opinion you should really consider overlaying text on top of the canvas and handle styles with CSS. [Here](http://codepen.io/arthursw/pen/xZONEg) is an example:

html:

```
<canvas id="PaperCanvas"></canvas>
<div id="container">
  <div id="text" contenteditable='true'>
    Your text
  </div>
</div>
```

coffeescript:

```
  ### ... some paper.js code ...
  # drag & drop:
  $('#container').mousedown (event)->
    if event.target.id != "container"
      return
    global.drag = true
    global.delta = new Point( $('#container').offset().left  - event.pageX, $('#container').offset().top - event.pageY)
    $("#text").addClass("noselect")
    return

  $("html").mousemove (event)->
    if global.drag
      $('#container').css( left: event.pageX + global.delta.x, top: event.pageY + global.delta.y)
    return

  $("html").mouseup (event)->
    global.drag = false
    $("#text").removeClass("noselect")
    return
```

css:

```
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: 'red';
}
#text {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: 'white';
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

*http://paperjs.org/reference/textitem/

> The TextItem type allows you to create typography. Its functionality is inherited by different text item types such as PointText, and AreaText (coming soon).

**Edit**

You can then use [html-to-canvas](https://github.com/Irrelon/html-to-canvas) or [rasterizeHTML.js](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/) to convert your colored text into an image that you can paste onto the paper.js canvas at the correct location. (You can use [Raster](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#raster) to import your image into paper.js)

Comment: could I get a little more information on how you're thinking overlaying text on top of the canvas will work? The text also needs to be draggable.

Comment: @arthur.sw - I did text annotation on top of an image a while back and took the approach you're suggesting. Using HTML text worked quite well and offered the full range of capabilities.

Comment: That looks like good code. The last step for me be creating an image out of all the annotations on the canvas, which would mean inserting the text made with the code above onto the new image being saved. How possible would that be? How would the HTML be flattened with the canvas?

Comment: Hum... this is not trivial, but you should have a look at [html-to-canvas](https://github.com/Irrelon/html-to-canvas) or [rasterizeHTML.js](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/) to convert your colored text into an image that you can paste onto the paper.js canvas at the correct place. I'll add this in my answer.