# Paper.js / canvas: smoothen text's slow movement

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

See this example: http://merijn.pro/ballen/
fiddle: http://tinyurl.com/o8gq7z2

The balls move around slowly, and the balls themselves render smoothly, 
but their text labels do not (they snap to the pixel grid). It looks ugly, because of the slow movement.

I am looking for a way to make the text render smoothly, if possible.
They are created as follows:

```
this.text = new PointText(this.point);
this.text.justification = 'center';
this.text.fillColor = 'black';
this.text.content = text;
```

and updated as follows:

```
this.text.position = this.point;
```

UPDATE: I tried to solve it by importing the texts as SVGs (containing the text), but this gave the same issue

[image]

Comment: If you can post the code as a sketch I'd be happy to play with it. I have two initial thoughts: 1) make the pointText and circle a group then move the group, not the two items, and 2) overlay the canvas with HTML text of some sort and position them absolutely with respect to the canvas. paper's text support is limited.

Comment: Please do! See http://tinyurl.com/o8gq7z2. I did consider option (2) but as you can understand I prefer a canvas-only way... I've also tried things like css transforming/translating the canvas, but the pixel snap stays. I'm eager to see what you can make from it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems to move both the text and circles smoothly though I haven't tested directly with your code. It's option (1) in my comment above - add the circle and the text to a group and just move the group.

[sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/bZJfb4IwFMW/ypUXMGMEiHth8cnEvZklLtkD8FDLFRtra0rVbcbvvlv+OLaMpEm5v3sO57ZcPcUO6GXeeo+W77zQ47py74XiCcxB4QVemd1FC2G4xCBP4jikVYaQxtNn1xU11ug9LrTUhhS+wconQCj9z2AWhzAb6dO/+togqs7BDgZaKPuGHza4FgroObpCBvkTmT2RWVflWll0dX+tDwiWBH6PtkLK9gsEN5Lx/R2QZskOQn4SWeiTEWhghZcxf0dR75ztRstqDNbiCzNI0kLdpm3gug/8YvTpGOQ8CYGnIdiyw2dmoEJpGbXlxJKyLW9PiluhFWi1NHQdwRT6OcUWgslZ4CXa6JOqmsiNyIRqgjo66ka0qofOc3pXDcq2nMclTOZzWLHVr4bbz5ZMGy0xkrruNC7tAO95Hwe7EPptUpZ9Y282DjXvlH0DnZCbtFD0h20Msn17g42X5eXtGw==)

Even implementing a countdown as in the comment below the movement isn't smooth. It looks like the screen's physical pixels create a barrier to moving text smoothly by using paper. I don't have a solution other than always moving units of pixels.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to group the objects but unfortunately it doesn't make the text move smoothly on slow movement. Your vector is [1,1] so every time it moves 1 pixel and then it is smooth, but if I make it slower ([0.1,0.1]) it has the same problem like before: http://tinyurl.com/zny3vru

Comment: Yes, I just tried that myself and I saw the same thing you did. That seems to be the problem - the text only moves in increments of 1 pixel while the circle can move in smaller increments (due to interpolation). I don't have a solution for that.

Comment: You can have the items move 1 pixel at a time by using an update increment counter rather than a specific vector length. So if you want to move [0.1, 0.1] each time then set a counter of 10, decrement it on each Frame, and then move the ball by [1.0, 1.0] when the counter hits zero (and reset the counter to 10). That approach would keep the balls and the text in sync.

Comment: I think that only makes it look worse :) I'm afraid I have to go with your first suggestion to overlay the canvas with HTML, or somehow manage to load the text not as a text object but as a vector. But first thing I'm gonna do is to show this to the client to ask if they mind the jumpy text
Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer in a few days if I don't get another answer

Comment: It's not much of an answer. Marking it useful seems appropriate but I'm not sure it's an answer. Except maybe the HTML overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to handle text with html and css as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34405823/719276).

Text tools are still [in development](http://paperjs.org/reference/textitem/) in Paper.js.